# How to display custom posts according to settings made in a widget?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a widget in WordPress and a custom post type "**book**".

The widget gives user  an option to select the "**categories**" of the "**books**" post type.

Now, the problem for me is that after selecting the "**category**" in the widget how can I display the "**books**" of the selected category on the website ?

Comment: Is this a custom widget created in theme's function file?

Comment: No, it is created in my own php file. @Jainil

Comment: Have you created the widget class?

Answer (score 1):

In the `widget()` method of your widget class, you will need to set up a custom query to get the books to display based on the selected "category".

Since you didn't post any code for your widget form, I am making an assumption that you are saving the ID of the selected category to a `category_id` field when a widget is saved. Based on this assumption, you would use that category ID to query for the posts in your **books** post type so that the widget can display them wherever the widget is located on the frontend.

```
<?php
class MyWidget extends WP_Widget
{
    public function __construct(){}

    public function widget($args, $instance)
    {
        extract($args);

        $queryArgs = [
            'post_type' => 'book',
            'tax_query' => [
                [
                    'taxonomy' => 'custom_taxonomy_code',    // this would be the code for the custom taxonomy that you registered, i.e. your "category"
                    'field' => 'term_id',
                    'terms' => $instance['category_id']    // this assumes that your widget form saved the selected category ID to a 'category_id' field
                ]
            ],
            'posts_per_page' => 5 // or however many books you want to list
        ];
        $postsQuery = new WP_Query($queryArgs);

        if(!$postsQuery->have_posts())
        {
            print 'No books found.';
        }
        else
        {
            // display your books here
        }
    }

    public function update($newInstance, $oldInstance){}

    public function form($instance){}
}
```